# Nested html tables (child table width issue)

Tags: html, html-table, nested-table

I have some nested tables.

I have got a tr with two tds one is 14% and the other one is 86%.

The longer td contains another table. Now the width of the child table is quite long.

All I want to do is fit the child table in the longer td so it doesn’t over flow and instead it scrolls.

```css
table,td,th{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table class="display" id="dt3">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table_header">
      <th style="width:14%">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="schedule_view" style="width:86%;">Consultant schedule</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
      <td>
        John Dolan
      </td>
      <td class="schedule_view">
        <div style="overflow:hidden;">

          <table class="display">

            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>25-May
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>01-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>08-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>15-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>22-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>29-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>06-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>13-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>20-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>27-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>03-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>10-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>17-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>24-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>31-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>07-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>14-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>21-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>28-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>05-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>12-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>19-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>26-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>02-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>09-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>16-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>23-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>30-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
              <td>BOC</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>

            </tr>

          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <th></th>
      <th class="schedule_view" style="display:none;"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I think that's a typical case where you shouldn't use a table (your "parent" table) in the first place... the fact you only have 2 columns in that table and the first column doesn't even call for a heading is a good indicator. If what you're building is a list of people with schedules, just use a list and in each list item you can put name of people and schedule (in the form of a table this time, cause this is semantically correct)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some code. From what I understand, you could declare for the `td` containing the extra `table`:

```
td {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```css
td {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="display" id="dt3">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table_header">
      <th style="width:14%">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="schedule_view" style="width:86%;">Consultant schedule</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
      <td>
        John Dolan
      </td>
      <td class="schedule_view">
        <div style="overflow:hidden;">

          <table class="display">

            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>25-May
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>01-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>08-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>15-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>22-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>29-Jun
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>06-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>13-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>20-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>27-Jul
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>03-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>10-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>17-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>24-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>31-Aug
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>07-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>14-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>21-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>28-Sep
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>05-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>12-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>19-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>26-Oct
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>02-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>09-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>16-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>23-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
              <th>30-Nov
                <br />2015</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
              <td>BOC</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>100%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>0%</td>

            </tr>

          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <th></th>
      <th class="schedule_view" style="display:none;"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but result is the same. I have added some code and the image of the issue. Hopefully it will be clearer